# PySpark - Local system performance

Tags: pyspark

I am new to Pyspark. I would like to learn one while solving a Kaggle Challenge using a large dataset.

Does Pyspark offer performance advantage over Pandas when using on a local system?  Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running locally, pyspark runs with as many worker threads as logical cores available on your machine - if you run `spark.sparkContext.master`, it should return `local[*]` (more information on local configurations can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)). Since Pandas is single threaded (unless you're using something like [Dask](https://dask.org/)), for large datasets, Pyspark should be more performant. However, due to the overhead associated with using multiple threads, serializing data and sending to the JVM, etc., Pandas may be faster for smaller datasets.